# how to create a circular sprite in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, draw

I've tried to make a circular sprite in pygame. My sprite class:

```py
import pygame
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

class player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width, height, speed):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()

        # Pass in the color of the player, and its x and y position, width and height.
        # Set the background color and set it to be transparent
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)

        #Initialise attributes of the car.
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = speed

        # Draw the player
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image,self.color,self.speed,5)
```

This returns the error:

> ```py
> line 23, in __init__
>    pygame.draw.circle(self.image,self.color,self.speed,5)
> TypeError: argument 3 must be 2-item sequence, not int
> ```

so I have been trying different sources but I can never seem to figure out how to do it. So how do you make a circular sprite? It doesn't need to move or anything - I just need a small(ish) sprite.

Comment: Did you check [the official documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle)? `self.speed` is something you invented but it should be the draw coordinates.

Comment: When I tried the official documentation method @usr2564301 It didn't work - generally the official documentation confuses me

Comment: You find this confusing? "center (tuple(int or float, int or float) or list(int or float, int or float) or Vector2(int or float, int or float)) -- center point of the circle as a sequence of 2 ints/floats, e.g. (x, y)" What part of it? It may be concise but everything is in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3rd argument of [`pygame.draw.circle()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle) has to be a tuple with 2 components, the x and y center coordinated of the circle:

<s>`pygame.draw.circle(self.image,self.color,self.speed,5)`</s>

```py
pygame.draw.circle(self.image, self.color, (self.width//2, self.height//2), 5)
```

In the above example `(self.width//2, self.height//2)` is the center of the circle and `5` is the radius (in pixel).

See also
[Pygame Wont Let Me Draw A Circle Error argument 3 must be sequence of length 2, not 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62601880/pygame-wont-let-me-draw-a-circle-error-argument-3-must-be-sequence-of-length-2/62601934#62601934)

---

Furthermore a [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) object should always have a `.rect` attribute (instance of [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)):

```py
class player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width, height, speed):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()

        # [...]
        
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, self.color, (self.width//2, self.height//2), 5)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Note, the `.rect` and `.image` attribute of the `pygame.sprite.Sprite` object is used by the [`.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw), method of a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) to draw the contained sprites.

Thus a sprite can be moved by changing the position (e.g. `self.rect.x`, `self.rect.y`) encoded in the rectangle.

Comment: The name x is not defined - `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`